# Распределенные задания по расписанию

Tags: java, jms

Есть два сервера с WildFly и одна БД

Есть необходимость выполнять задания/действия по расписанию.

Требования:

1. Задание не должно потеряться при выключении одного или всех серверов
2. Должна быть возможность удалить еще не выполненное задание
3. Задание должно выполниться если работает хотя бы один из двух серверов

Стандартный таймер создаваемый через TimerService будет работать только на одном сервере, т.е. не подходит по п.3

JMS 2.0 - невозможно выполнить пункт 2

Можно и самому написать, но возможно есть существующий фреймворк про который я не знаю. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Посмотрите этот пример: https://github.com/sgilda/wildfly-quickstart/tree/master/cluster-ha-singleton . Там сразу несколько техник: таймер, кластерный компонент, клиент для управления компонентом (пункт 2). Сложновато на первый взгляд, но эти техники в комплексе могут решить Вашу задачу. Таймер будет запускаться на кластере (сервера, объединённые в кластер сами "решат" где запустить) - пункт 3. В TimerService.createCalendarTimer есть свойство persistent (пункт 1)

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.